how to make nvidia.com/gpu available in k8s node
when i describe node, there is no gpu resource, why?
(this is the node description)

I have installed nvidia driver
(this is nvidia driver for tesla p4)
I have installed nvidia container toolkit, and configured the runtime as containerd
(this is the containerd config for nvidia container runtime)
I have installed nvidia k8s plugin nvidia-device-plugin
(this is the nvidia device plugin for k8s)


This question seems to be about configuring your individual Kubernetes nodes and not about programming per se.  Another site like [sf] might be a more appropriate place to ask.  When you do, please do not upload images of code/data/errors: tools like kubectl write out plain text, and including the plain text is much easier to read and search for later.

ok, I will ask on Server Fault, thanks
